# CLLocationDistance not working - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, cllocation

I'm having problems with this code, I can't calculate the distance between two locations. I've already searched all over the internet but I could not solve it. Here is my didUpdateLocations function:

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    var startLocation = userLocation
    var endLocation = userLocation
    if x == 0 {
        var startLocation = userLocation
        star.text = "\(startLocation)"
    }
    if x > 0 {
        var endLocation = userLocation
        end.text = "\(endLocation)"
        let distance: CLLocationDistance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(endLocation)
        println(distance)
    }
    x = x + 1
}
```

Comment: I also looked at your answer but .. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to do a Run app, and in this code i want to know the distance of start-point to end-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare you  var startLocation as an optional but not inside your function.

```
var startLocation :CLLocation!
```

then inside your didUpdate function you just test if the startLocation var is nil:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = locations.first as? CLLocation
    }
    let distance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(locations.last as! CLLocation)
    println( "\(startLocation)")
    println( "\(locations.last as! CLLocation)")
    println("DISTANCE: \(distance)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tks a lot!

I've to do this changes

```
var startLocation :CLLocation!
var endLocation :CLLocation!

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

     var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = locations.first as? CLLocation
    }
    endLocation = locations.last as? CLLocation

    let distance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(endLocation)

        println("DISTANCE: \(distance)")
        VDistancia.text = "\(distance)"
        VInical.text = "\(startLocation)"
        VSpeed.text = "\(userLocation.speed)"

}
```

It's works! The values aren't correct, but I'll search how fix it. tks!